# Где ошибка, обьясните пожалуйста

Tags: pascal

```
var 
  a, b: real;
begin
  a := 1.36477;
  b := 2.7;
  if a > b then writeIn('a')
  else writeIn('b');
  readIn;
end.
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку((

Comment: Ошибки надо читать. Это очень полезный навык.

Answer (score 3):

Вы перепутали заглавную букву `I` (ай) со строчной буквой `l` (эл) в словах `writeLn` и `readLn`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Comment: @Александр Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.